# SQL Server stored procedure - inserting new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to insert records in `Table2` from `Table1` and that too insert with my new primary key specified.. I have written following stored procedure for that ::

```
DECLARE @Iterator INT, @tempCount INT, @Nbb_ID INT

SET @Iterator = 0
SET @tempCount = count('SELECT * FROM Table1')

WHILE (@Iterator < @tempCount)
BEGIN
    SET @Nbb_ID =   NEWID()

    INSERT INTO Table2 (Nbb_ID, Nbb_Name)
    VALUES (@Nbb_ID, (SELECT NAME1 FROM Table1 WHERE rownum = @Iterator + 1))

    SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
END
```

I don't understand where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What's wrong???? R u getting error? Wrong result or else?

Comment: (this is not ORACLE query)instead of rownum,,, i want to specify something so that i can fetch one by one record ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you're just wanting to copy the records from Table1 into Table2 but give a new ID to the Table2 record, then you can do this more efficiently by using

```
insert into Table2 
select NEWID(), NAME1 from Table1
```

This will evaluate NEWID() for each record that is being taken from Table1, thus giving the Table2 record a different UID.

The benefit over your method is that this is a set-based approach which is what DBs are best at. Your method is RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) which is not the best use of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.

So in your case, you need to change your `INSERT` statement to:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Nbb_ID, Nbb_Name)
   SELECT 
      NEWID(), NAME1 
   FROM 
      Table1
```

and that should do it - there's absolutely no need to create your own *row-by-agonizing-row* `WHILE` loop here.... just use a single, **set-based** statement and you're done!